# wpf different parts of a image animation

Tags: wpf, animation

[image: Letter G]
[image: Part of the letter G]
I need to implement a letter animation using different parts of a image.
now, using image2 Painted to image1.
Request help, be grateful!

Comment: Not sure what you're going to do, but you may start reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742562.aspx).